# Why # not work in query string?

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

In cs.aspx page i have a button with following code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("~/cs.aspx?p=ali#25");
}
```

In page_load i get query string and display it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["p"] != null)
    {
        string p = Request.QueryString["p"];
        Response.Write("p= "+p);
    }
}
```

in query string:

```
p  = ali#25
```

but in run time display

```
p = ali
```

why string after # not shown.

Comment: `#` is a reserved character and has meaning in urls; the part of the URL after `#` is **never** sent to the server. If you mean to represent the **value** `"ali#25"`, you will need to *url-encode* it - but you should be doing that anyway, as a matter of routine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found a solution. use  **Server.UrlEncode**:

```
Response.Redirect("~/cs.aspx?pass="+Server.UrlEncode("a#25"));
```

Comment: For completeness, the `#` is being treated as a page anchor. See http://www.echoecho.com/htmllinks08.htm

Comment: You should always use Url-Encoding before sending the actual values to URL